# GlSurfaceView setZMediaOrder causing video to play outside its parents

Tags: android, glsurfaceview, z-order

**Case-1:**

```
GLSurfaceView
|
FrameLayout
|
TextureView
|
VideoRecording
```

So here I have a `GLSurfaceView`, based on user input I am adding a square `FrameLayout` on top of it (dimensions are set using layoutparams) and then adding `TextureView` on top of this newly added `FrameLayout` and then recording the video, As expected, irrespective of what camera choose, I get a square preview.

**Case-2:**

```
GLSurfaceView
|
FrameLayout
|
GLSurfaceView
|
VideoPlayback
```

In the case-1 after recording the video I am adding another `GLSurfaceView` by removing the previous `TextureView` from the already added `FrameLayout`. Earlier, I could just hear the sound of playback without any video, but later I came across examples which were using
`setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);` 
or 
`setZOrderOnTop(true)` 
Now the video plays, but instead of playing within its parent, its playing in 9/16 aspect ratio. As mentioned earlier, Expected behavior is square video (Dimensions of the FrameLayout).

How can I get the newly added video on top of background video without getting it out of the bounds of its parents.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check media player aspect ratio and set according to that, use relative layout instead of frame layout and set gravity CENTER, and implement this code:

```
MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener mOnVideoSizeChangedListener = new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {

            setAspectRatio(mp, width, height);

        }
    };
```

And create a method and set video layout params according to this:

```
  private void setAspectRatio(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int videoWidth, int videoHeight)
{
    if(mediaPlayer != null)
    {

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams videoParams = getLayoutParams();


        if (videoWidth > videoHeight)
        {
            videoParams.width = width;
            videoParams.height = width * videoHeight / videoWidth;
        }
        else
        {
            videoParams.width = height * videoWidth / videoHeight;
            videoParams.height = height;
        }

        // Commit params
        surfaceView.setLayoutParams(videoParams);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Harsh, The question is not about resizing the surface.